# Angular customer directive with filter and sort

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need to sort the json object with one of the userType thru ng-repeat. Now i was able to retrieve and display the data, and ISSUE is that I need to sort and display two different table the below list; One is for MARRIED and another for SINGLE.

How can i sort married/single when i use ng-repeat, and need to show in TWO tables. Any suggestions/help will be appreciated....

```
.controller('userInfo', ['$scope', 'userService', function ($scope, userService) {
      userService.getuserList().then(function (users) {
        users = {
                "personalInfo": {
                    "firstName": "Richardoo",
                    "lastName": "Gil",
                    "maritalStatus": "Married",                    
                    "percentage": "50"
        },"personalInfo": {
                    "firstName": "Richardoo",
                    "lastName": "Gil",
                    "maritalStatus": "Single",                    
                    "percentage": "50"
        },
        "personalInfo": {
                    "firstName": "Richardoo",
                    "lastName": "Gil",
                    "maritalStatus": "Married",                    
                    "percentage": "50"
        }}

        $scope.users = users;
      });
    }])

.directive('userDetails', function () {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
          users: '='
        },
        controller: function ($scope) {
          $scope.showEdit = function () {
            $scope.isEdit = true;
          }
        },
        template: `<div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table">
          <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Relation</th>
                  <th>Percentage</th>
                  <th></th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              <tr data-ng-repeat="user in users">
                  <td>{{user.personalInfo.firstName}} {{user.personalInfo.lastName}}</td>
                  <td>{{user.userRelations.relationshipType}}</td>
                  <td><span ng-if="!isEdit">{{user.personalInfo.percent}}</span><input type="text"
                          ng-if="isEdit" ng-model="user.personalInfo.percent" class="form-control"></td>
                  <td><a ng-click="showEdit()" href="#">Update</a></td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
          <tfoot>
              <tr>
                  <td colspan="2">Total Percentage</td>
                  <td>100%</td>
                  <td><a ng-if="!isEdit" ng-click="showEdit()" href="#">Update</a><a ng-if="isEdit" ng-click="showEdit()" href="#">Save Percentage</a></td>
              </tr>
          </tfoot>
      </table>
  </div>`
      };
    })

    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <h1>Update User Information</h1>
            <div data-ng-controller="user">
                <div data-ng-controller="userInfo">
                    <user-details user="users"></user-details>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

users in your answer is not a valid object as it has "personalInfo" as key multiple times. You should instead create an array of objects like :

```
         users = [{
                    "firstName": "Richardoo",
                    "lastName": "Gil",
                    "maritalStatus": "Married",                    
                    "percentage": "50"
                 },{
                    "firstName": "Richardoo",
                    "lastName": "Gil",
                    "maritalStatus": "Single",                    
                    "percentage": "50"
               },{
                    "firstName": "Richardoo",
                    "lastName": "Gil",
                    "maritalStatus": "Married",                    
                    "percentage": "50"
               }];
```

For creating two tables, for married and single,

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <h1>Update User Information</h1>
           <div data-ng-controller="user">
               <div data-ng-controller="userInfo">
                  <user-details user="users" userfilter="single"></user-details>
                  <user-details user="users" userfilter="married"></user-details>
               </div>
            </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

**Change in userDetails directive template function**

```
          <tbody>
              <tr data-ng-repeat="user in users | filter:{maritalStatus:$attrs.userfilter}">
                  <td>{{user.personalInfo.firstName}} {{user.personalInfo.lastName}}</td>
                  <td>{{user.userRelations.relationshipType}}</td>
                  <td><span ng-if="!isEdit">{{user.personalInfo.percent}}</span><input type="text"
                          ng-if="isEdit" ng-model="user.personalInfo.percent" class="form-control"></td>
                  <td><a ng-click="showEdit()" href="#">Update</a></td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
```

Comment: Thank you,  I've added like this in directive, 
              <tr data-ng-repeat="user in users" | filter: { maritalStatus:$attrs.userfilter}>., and HTML - added the userfilter. But not working, Do i need to inject the $attrs in directive?

Comment: i was able to filter the data thru **bold**`code`<tr data-ng-repeat="user in users | filter: user.personalInfo.maritalStatus='Single'">`code`**bold**.... But not able to read the ATTRIBUTE from html. Anyone please guide me...

Comment: Add $attrs.userfilter as a scope property in link function or controller and use it as a scope property in template instead as a $attr.userfilter. This should work.

Comment: Something like this:
template: '<div> {{abc}} </div>', // here it's scope.abc
link : function (scope, elem, attr) {
    scope.abc = attr.abc;
}

Comment: `code`.directive('userDetails', function () {
      return {restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
          users: '=',
userFilter: '@'
        },
link: function ($scope) {
         console.log('scope=', $scope.userFilter); ///Here getting the value from html.     } },
        template: `<tr data-ng-repeat="user in users | filter: {user.personalInfo.martialStatus: userFilter}"> `};
    })`code`. Filter in NOT working -**bold** {user.personalInfo.martialStatus:userFilter}**bold**but when i hardcode the value, like **bold**user.personalInfo.martialStatus= 'Single';**bold** is working fine.

Comment: `code`<tr data-ng-repeat="user in users| filter: user.personalInfo.martialStatus= '{{userFilter}}' ">. `code` How to inject the userFilter scope data to filter. When i hardcode the value, then it's working fine.

Comment: template: <tr data-ng-repeat="user in users | filter: {user.personalInfo.martialStatus: **{{userFilter}}**}"

Comment: thank you @Nishi Jain. I tried this, but got error `code`VM23223:10126 Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'userFilter' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 48 of the expression [users | filter: {user.personalInfo.martialStatus: {{userFilter}}}] starting at [userFilter}}}]`code`

Comment: Jain. it's working perfectly now. Thanks a lot for your help. I made changes as **bold**`code`<tr data-ng-repeat="user in users| filter: user.personalInfo.martialStatus= userFilter  ">`code`**bold**

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="user in users | filter:{maritalStatus:userfilter}"></tr>
```

$scope.sortType = 'x.user'

Comment: `code`<tr data-ng-repeat="user in users| filter: user.personalInfo.martialStatus= '{{userFilter}}' ">. `code` How to inject the userFilter scope data to filter. When i hardcode the value, then it's working fine.